# Convert IIS log file in to Apache common log format

Tags: apache, iis, logging

What are the converters available for converting an IIS log file in to Apache common log format?

I found the following link, but I need any other tool which is not mentioned here.

http://www.cmsproducer.com/analysis/iis-w3c-ncsa-logs-convert

Answer (score 1):

You can try Log Parser Lizard, which may help you, with a little bit of work. It does exporting to custom formats and all sorts, quite powerful.

[Log Parser Lizard](http://www.lizard-labs.net/log_parser_lizard.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to the answer above; There's now a programmatical way of doing this using the new [Tx (LINQ to Logs and Traces)](http://tx.codeplex.com/) library up on CodePlex.

It's been built for .NET use only though, and is available as a nuget package. Essentially it lets you create any kind of transformation you can write code for over your log files (or event streams), even in real-time (you can pretty much tail an existing, currently running log if you want to)